# Blender file won't open

Tags: blend-files

[image]When I open my file, Blender opens for a second (as shown below) and then closes.

[image]

Comment: What does the console say? It is probably telling you what the error is...just look at the other Blender window. Also, what version of Blender are you using? From the image I notice that it is in a folder with `-`'s in it which could potentially cause problems on Windows...also that path looks very suspicious to me anyhow...

Comment: i'm using the version 2.79b.i can't understand the console(it's the picture above).

Comment: That error is fine...I have always had that message on any OS. Perhaps this is a permissions error, so you could check if you have read/write access to that file. Otherwise, start it from the console with `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\blender.exe -d` (or wherever Blender is installed, just make sure to use the `-d` debug flag) and post the output.

Comment: the read/write access to that file is okey.Someone told me that i maybe pressed a wrong key and corrupted my file is there any way to fix it??

Comment: There is often no easy way to fix a corrupted file, but try what I mentioned in the last comment to see if that says anything useful...